While iterating over a list, the index being used resets before finishing the list
I am doing some Codewars practice and got this problem. The goal is to determine if the word provided text ends with ending. The solution I have works with every test case but (sumo, omo). For some reason, the for loop returns to 0 after 1. This does not occur with any other test case.
def solution(text, ending):
    text_list = list(text)
    ending_list = list(ending)
    results_list = []
    text_list.reverse()
    ending_list.reverse()

    if len(text_list) >= len(ending_list):
        for i in ending_list:
            num = ending_list.index(i)
            if ending_list[num] == text_list[num]:
                results_list.append(0)
                print(num)
            else:
                results_list.append(1)
            
        if sum(results_list) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

Above is my Code
from solution import solution
import codewars_test as test
from random import randint

fixed_tests_True = (
    ( "samurai", "ai"    ),
    ( "ninja",   "ja"    ),
    ( "sensei",  "i"     ),
    ( "abc",     "abc"   ),
    ( "abcabc",  "bc"    ),
    ( "fails",   "ails"  ),
)

fixed_tests_False = (
    ( "sumo",    "omo"   ),
    ( "samurai", "ra"    ),
    ( "abc",     "abcd"  ),
    ( "ails",    "fails" ),
    ( "this",    "fails" ),
    ( "spam",    "eggs"  )
)

@test.describe("Fixed Tests")
def test_group():
    @test.it("True Cases")
    def test_case():
        for text, ending in fixed_tests_True:
            test.assert_equals(solution(text, ending), True)
    @test.it("False Cases")
    def test_case():
        for text, ending in fixed_tests_False:
            test.assert_equals(solution(text, ending), False)

Above is the test case provided.

Doesn't Python have an endswith method for strings?

Indeed it does, which is probably the solution I was supposed to come up with. I'd still love to know whats happening to my code though.

The problem's in this line:
num = ending_list.index(i)

When ending_list has duplicative characters, this is only going to find the index of the last appearance (first in the reversed list). So if you have text=sumo and ending=omo, your program will get to the third iteration and follow these steps:

Realize that the current letter is "o".
Figure out what the first occurrence of "o" is in the reversed list.
Find that the first occurrence is at index 0.
Realize that index 0 in the two reversed lists are the same.

To be honest, I'm not sure why you're using index at all...just iterate over a range instead so you can get the indexes directly:
def solution(text, ending):
    text_list = list(text)
    ending_list = list(ending)
    results_list = []
    text_list.reverse()
    ending_list.reverse()

    if len(text_list) >= len(ending_list):
        for i in range(len(ending_list)):
            if ending_list[i] == text_list[i]:
                results_list.append(0)
            else:
                results_list.append(1)
            
        if sum(results_list) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

print(solution("sumo", "omo")) # False
print(solution("sumo", "umo")) # True


Looking back on this, I'd probably use zip and enumerate instead of iterating over a range. I'm hesitant to actually edit the answer, though.
